# How to send emails in development environment using gmail SMTP and devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to send emails while being on localhost and using devise (I need emails for user registration and password reset)

I have put this in my environment.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["username"],
    password: ENV["password"]

}

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

but I am not getting any mails and not seeing any error too (devise says ).

- What am I missing ?
- Where can I see the log for emails (success or
  failure) ?

EDIT - OK, it worked after adding this line

```
:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
```

Check this too [rails email error - 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724906/rails-email-error-530-5-5-1-authentication-required/11725153#11725153)

Comment: have you configured `config/initializers/devise.rb` with `config.mailer_sender = "<email>"`  . In addition to this, also set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to check for any errors

Comment: yes, I have added the same email id at config.mailer_sender which I have kept as smtp username, still no email

Comment: as Nishant has staetd make sure config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true otherwise you wont see any errors. are there any problems with your ENV variables, though would be better to place them in a yml file and load them when initializing..

Comment: @Richlewis - Rich, I have set it as true and I am seeing "You will receive an email with instructions ..." message rather then some error, still not getting any email

Comment: ok, have you checked your spam folder, this sometimes happens with gmail

Comment: and to clarify config.mailer_sender = "your gmail address"

Comment: @Richlewis - Thanks Rich, I solved the problem, I had to add ":openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'" too. I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724906/rails-email-error-530-5-5-1-authentication-required/11725153#11725153,

Comment: glad you got it working though have never heard of or used that option before

Comment: @Nishant not my question and I didnt solve it, think you meant to post this to iCyborg

Comment: @iCyborg Would be better, if you post the part that worked as an answer instead of an edit to the question and accept your own answer.

Comment: @Richlewis :) deleted that one. and addressed to icyborg