# Net::OpenTimeout in Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

I am using actionmailer to send registration verification details of devise to users but I am getting following error:

**Net::OpenTimeout in Users::RegistrationsController#create**

my development.rb looks like:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 :port => 25,
 :domain => 'gmail.com',
 :user_name => 'example@gmail.com',
 :password => 'secret',
 :authentication => 'plain',
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :ssl => true
 }
```

I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040158/rails-mailer-netopentimeout-execution-expired-exception-on-production-serve) question and added

```
#disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

command:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

return 1. It didn't make difference to my error. Also tried changing port from 587 to 2525.
So I tried establish connection with server from command line:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 2525
```

got:

```
Trying 74.125.68.108...
Trying 74.125.68.109...
Trying 2404:6800:4003:c02::6c...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

I even tried adding firewall rules using [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1876124). I followed second method (ufw) but I am still getting same error.

Comment: Did you try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`?

Comment: yup. /etc/services has: `telnet    23/tcp`. I tried that too but everthing leads to `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable`

Comment: Di dyou ever figure this out?

Comment: nope! I am using heroku for hosting and there email settings seem to work fine but locally it doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with my ISP

Comment: I suppose email settings are correct but make sure port 23, 587 & 25 are open on heroku.

Comment: you mentioned this isn't working locally but does work on heroku. Can you access your personal gmail account over SMTP (i.e. with a mail client) over this connection? It sounds like your ISP may be blocking ports or something...