# Not able to send eamil from heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to send email using `SMTP` server on`heroku run rails console` but getting some error. But it is working absolutely fine on local system, not able to understand what's the problem.

Code:

```
message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: Jobs<notification@example.com>
To: Ajay Gupta<ajaygupta@example.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('SMTP_URL') do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message 'message', 'ajaygupta@example.com', 'ajaygupta@example.com'
end
```

Error: when run the above code on heroku console

```
Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/smtp.rb:457:in `start'
        from (irb):3
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040158/rails-mailer-netopentimeout-execution-expired-exception-on-production-serve

Answer (score 0):

It appears based on your call `heroku run rails console`, that you are trying to run this on a Heroku based server. According to Heroku's own [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp), you are only allowed to send email using an external service, such as [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) or other providers.