# 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In `order_mailer.rb`:

```
default from: 'notifications@example.com'

def welcome_email(order)
 @user = "Uday kumar das"
 @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
 mail(to: 'dasudaykumar017@gmail.com', subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
end
```

In `orders_conroller`:

```
def delivery
 @order1 = Order.where(:orderId=>params[:orderId])
 @order = Order.find(@order1)
 OrderMailer.welcome_email(@order).deliver
end
```

In `environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I am new to mails in rails.I am referring http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html to learn. I am getting error like:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError in OrdersController#delivery`
>
> 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at`

Comment: Solution is at this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724906/rails-email-error-530-5-5-1-authentication-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same using my gmail, following are my configurations, try and see it if works

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {

                :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
                :port           => 587,
                :authentication => :plain,
                :user_name      => "<my gmail>@gmail.com",
                :password       => "<my gmail password>",
                :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none' }
```

Please note the:

`:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'`

section to skip the ssl errors